# Unable to perform anything after AsynchronusRequest in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working with Swift first time. I am firing Web API as shown below and I am getting data successfully but I am unable to perform any thing in **NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest** black. I am printing result after that I have wrote segue perform method and but it not pushing to another ViewController and it stay in same view controller. Thanks in advance.

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            //SwiftLoader.hide()
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                     SwiftLoader.hide()
                    print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self)
                }
                self.hideView()
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a segue it should perform on main thread , not in a background thread. NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest run on background thread, so if you want any UI related modification, you should use main thread. so use like this :-

```
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        //SwiftLoader.hide()
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                 SwiftLoader.hide()
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self)                                          
                })

            }
            self.hideView()
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform UI operation on main thread. Currently you re doing it on worker thread. With help of GCD, get main thread and dispatch Segue operation on it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

    print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self)
 })
```

Comment: I didn't understand can you please tell me bit more